# Is there an easy way to stack Comparison operators in c#?

Tags: c#, comparison

In c# any type that implements comparison operators like `<` `>`, can easily be compared. For example I can do this:

```
var date1 = new DateTime(1000);
var date2 = new DateTime(2000);
var date3 = new DateTime(3000);
var result = date1 < date2; // true
```

However, i'm not able to do the following

```
var result = date1 < date2 < date3; // error
```

> this doesn't compile, since the first comparison returns a boolean, which isn't further compareable to other dates

So I have to do it like this instead (`DateTime.CompareTo(DateTime)` returns -1 if first `DateTime` is earlier:

```
var result = date1.CompareTo(date2) + date2.CompareTo(date3) == -2; // true
```

Or simply do this:

```
var result = date1 < date2 && date2 < date3; // true
```

However, I was wondering if there was some possibility to chain the `<` Operator multiple times, for the ease of writing some easier to read code, when this is used in more complicated scenarios.

For example I need to do this (which of course doen't compile):

```
result = 
    date1 < date2 < date3 < date4 ||
    date3 < date4 < date1 < date2 ||
    date4 < date1 < date2 < date3 ||
    date2 < date3 < date4 < date1
```

which would lead to much easier readable code than the above presented possibilities which work.

Is there an easy way to do this, do I need to implement it myself?

Comment: It is always a good idea to check the issue tracker of the C# project on Github. There is already a proposal for chaining comparison operators: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/217. Note the comments about how unintuitive comparison chaining becomes when _bool_ arguments/variables are involved. Also note the comment by _ufcpp_ referring to a possible solution/workaround: https://gist.github.com/ufcpp/3509ba373ab1622ac9b77e78dea26ecc

Comment: There is no way to do exactly that.  The best you can do is to write a method like `InOrder(params DateTime[] dates)` and you can do `InOrder(date1, date2, date3, date4) || ....`

Comment: Further to @juharr's excellent suggestion: `InOrder<T>(params T[] values) where T : IComparable ...`

Comment: @juharr yes, I thought about that

Comment: Also I'd suggest not adding the results of `CompareTo` as technically less than is only represented as a negative number and the -1 is an implementation detail.  Granted I don't know of any implementations that don't just use -1, but they could.  And on top of that it makes for more confusing code than just using logic operators.

Comment: `public static bool InOrder<T>(params T[] values) where T : struct, IComparable => 
            !values.Zip(values.Skip(1), (value, nextValue) => value.CompareTo(nextValue)).Any(x => x >= 0);` -- `struct` constraint is so I don't have to worry about null item comparisons. I'm also assuming that equal items are "out of order", as you're using `>` not `>=`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett this is a very neat solution. And yes, the `>=` sort of doesnt fit the scenario. Can you explain how exactly it works, since there is a lot of confusing syntax.

Comment: @elgonzo checked out the second link.. Just amazing what ufcpp did there.

Comment: @LuckyLikey, yeah, it's pretty clever...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool InOrderAscending<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values) 
        where T : struct, IComparable 
    =>
        !values.Zip(values.Skip(1), (value, nextValue) => value.CompareTo(nextValue))
             .Any(x => x >= 0);

    public static bool InOrderAscending<T>(params T[] values) where T : struct, IComparable 
        => values.InOrderAscending();
}
```

Here's how that works: `Zip()` takes two IEnumerables and enumerates the items in 
them as matched pairs:

```
var a = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var b = new[] { 4, 5, 6, 7 };

var zipped = a.Zip(b, (aitem, bitem) => $"{aitem},{bitem}").ToList();
```

zipped will contain `{ "1, 4", "2, 5", "3, 6" }`.

Note that `7` is unused: There's no match so it's discarded. This is in accordance with the LINQ philosophy of never having to do range-checking.

Next, `Skip(1)` skips one item and enumerates the rest.

So what I'm doing is zipping two sequences: The original one, and the second-through-final items of the original one.

```
{a, b, c}
{b, c}
```

So that'll give us a sequence of (a, b) and (b, c).

This is less readable than comparing `arg[i]` to `arg[i+1]`, but it spares you dealing with indexes.

So our zip expression returns a sequence of *comparison* results. For each adjacent pair of items, we call CompareTo() and return the result.

```
public static bool InOrderDescending<T>(params T[] values) where T : struct, IComparable
{
    List<int> comparisons = 
        values.Zip(values.Skip(1), (value, nextValue) => value.CompareTo(nextValue))
              .ToList();

    //  Now we finish by checking that sequence of integers for any positive values, 
    //  where a positive value means that `value` was greater than `nextValue`
    var haveOutOfOrderItems = comparisons.Any(x => x >= 0);

    //  If none of the values were positive, we're in order. 
    return !haveOutOfOrderItems;
}
```

I've written this method for value types only, so I don't have to worry about nulls. Is `null` greater or lesser than `new Button()` or `this.SettingsPage`? That's up to the caller, so I'd write a reference-type overload that takes a parameter of type `IComparer<T>`, or just a lambda (Edit: Perhaps we should actually write an extension method that does the self-offset-zip, but returns a sequence of some arbitrary return type from the lambda; we’d use that to write this).

```
public static bool InOrderAscending<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, Func<T, T, int> compare) 
    where T : class 
=>
    !values.Zip(values.Skip(1), (value, nextValue) => compare(value, nextValue))
        .Any(x => x >= 0);
```

Comment: jeez.. this is so genious. Thanks for taking the time to explain it.

Comment: Actually it could be a lot better, but we just went to a team lunch, so it’ll have to do.

Comment: level of perfection - ed plunkett? ;)

Comment: however I'd love to see how you would improve this solution even more.

Comment: @LuckyLikey Looking at it again, I don't think there's much real value to be added. I'd add analagous `InOrderReverse` methods, and I'd want a set of similar methods for `<=`, where ( 1, 2, 2, 3 ) is "in order".

Comment: yea, dont hesitate, I think i could do those myself if needed. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

as @Ed Plunkett and @juharr suggested, I implemented `InOrder()`

```
public static bool InOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) where T : struct, IComparable
{
    var array = collection.ToArray();
    if (array.Length < 2)
        return true;
    var comp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        comp += array[i].CompareTo(array[i + 1]);
    }

    return comp == 1 - array.Length;
}

public static bool InOrder<T>(params T[] args) where T: struct, IComparable
{
    return args.InOrder();
}
```

It produces the following output

```
var date1 = new DateTime(1000);
var date2 = new DateTime(2000);
var date3 = new DateTime(3000);
var result = InOrder(date1, date2); // true
var result1 = InOrder(date2, date1); // false
var result2 = InOrder(date1, date2, date3); // true
var result3 = InOrder(date1, date3, date2); // false
```

Comment: I'd constrain that as `struct` as well, so as not to worry about nulls. I'd also return `true` on `args.Length < 2`; in my view a list of one item is not out of order, and not an exception. You can pass this thing an array if you like. Actually, in practice I'd write it as an extension method to `IEnumerable<T>`, and write the `params` version would just call the extension method.

Comment: @EdPlunkett you mean like `where T : struct, IComparable` ? Doesn't this prevent it from being used by classes that implement `IComparable`. I agree on the return value.

Comment: I would write a separate overload for reference types, which takes an IComparer to compare them, because I don't think it's necessarily obvious whether `null` is greater or lesser than `new Button()`, so I'd rather leave that to the caller to decide instead of asking him to guess which way I guessed.

Comment: I'm writing an answer.

Comment: @EdPlunkett totally aggreed :)